# How do I add an unbound field to a form in Symfony which is otherwise bound to an entity?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

Maybe I'm missing the obvious but how do I (or can I) add an extra "unbound" field to a Symfony form that is otherwise bound to an entity?

Let's say I have an entity with fields `first_name` and `last_name`. I do the typical thing in my form class `buildForm` method.

```
$builder
    ->add('first_name')
    ->add('last_name')
;
```

and this in my controller:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new MyType(), $entity);
```

That works nicely but I'd like to add another text box, let's call it "extra", and receive the value in the POST action. If I do `$builder->add('extra')‍`, it complains that

> NoSuchPropertyException in PropertyAccessor.php line 479:
>
> Neither the property "extra" nor one of the methods "getExtra()", "extra()", "isExtra()", "hasExtra()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class...

Which is correct. I just want to use it to collect some extra info from the user and do something with it other than storing it with the entity.

I know how to make a completely standalone form but not one that's "mixed".
Is this possible?

Comment: https://speakerdeck.com/u/bschussek/p/symfony-form-tricks slide 55

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In your form add a text field with a false property_path:

```
$builder->add('extra', 'text', array('property_path' => false));
```

You can then access the data in your controller:

```
$extra = $form->get('extra')->getData();
```

**UPDATE**

The new way since Symfony 2.1 is to use the `mapped` option and set that to `false`.

`->add('extra', null, array('mapped' => false))`

Credits for the update info to Henrik Bjørnskov ( comment below )

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that. It's right there in "The Book".

Comment: The new way for Symfony 2.1 is to use the `mapped` option and set that to `false`

Answer (score 30):

Since Symfony 2.1, use the `mapped` option:

```php
$builder->add('extra', 'text', [
    'mapped' => false,
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields):

**allow_extra_fields**

> Usually, if you submit extra fields that aren't configured in your form, you'll get a "This form should not contain extra fields." validation error.
>
> You can silence this validation error by enabling the `allow_extra_fields` option on the form.

**mapped**

> If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the object, you can set the `mapped` option to false.

```
class YourOwnFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'allow_extra_fields' => true
            )
        );
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $form = $builder
            ->add('extra', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Extra field'
                'mapped' => false
            ))
        ;
        return $form;
    }
}
```