# Symfony2 - Sending other data along with form data via Ajax causes IsValid() to return false

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation, symfony

I'm trying to send other data along with a submitted form to a controller inside Symfony2.

When I try this like:

```
$("#submit_btn").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: post_url,
            data: form.serialize()
        });
    });
```

I see i got a successful `POST` request followed by a redirect as intended inside the controller action, If `IsValid()` returned true.

But when I try to send other data with the form like:

```
$("#submit_btn").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: post_url,
            data: { form: form.serialize(), otherdata: "test" }
        });
    });
```

I do not get the redirection `302` response. instead I get only one `200` response when means `IsValid()` method returned false. My question here how to not only send form, but also other data with it ?

Here's my controller action:

```
public function postOverviewAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $overview = $this->get("doctrine_mongodb")->getRepository("GbrBEBundle:Overview")->findOneById($id);
        $overview_photos = $this->get("doctrine_mongodb")->getRepository("GbrBEBundle:OverviewPhoto")->findAll();
        $form = $this->createForm(new OverviewType(), $overview);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $height = $form->get("coordinate_height")->getData();
        $width = $form->get("coordinate_width")->getData();
        $x = $form->get("coordinate_x")->getData();
        $y = $form->get("coordinate_y")->getData();

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $overview->setCropCoordinates(array('height' => $height, 'width' => $width, 'x' => $x, 'y' => $y));
            $dm = $this->get("doctrine_mongodb")->getManager();
            $dm->persist($overview);
            $dm->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("gbr_be_get_overview"));
        }
        return $this->render("GbrBEBundle:Default:overview.html.twig", array(
            "form" => $form->createView(),
            "overview" => $overview,
            "overview_photos" => $overview_photos,
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an unmapped field to the form:

[How do I add an unbound field to a form in Symfony which is otherwise bound to an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765368/how-do-i-add-an-unbound-field-to-a-form-in-symfony-which-is-otherwise-bound-to-a)

Setting to type `text` should prove the most versatile.

You can also create a `collection` field as the unmapped field, and assign the `text` type to it.  This will allow you to have multiple additional text data on the receiving end.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: First, Thanks for your answer. My problem is not with the unmapped fields. It's with sending a request that not only include the form data but also other variables set inside jquery. Symfony have some mechanism on calling `IsValid()` method. So apparently it thinks that the form is not posted at all, While in fact it's posted with other variables inside a collection created in jQuery.

Comment: Are you also sending the token?

Answer (score 0):

may be try to change:

```
 data: { form: form.serialize(), otherdata: "test" }
```

by
     data: form.serialize()+'&otherdata=test',

i think its because .serialize() return a string.