# Add an input tag if a check box has been selected in a form type in symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am a new symfony user. I am generating a form using a form type. I have generated a set of check boxes and would like to have an input field display if one of the check boxes has been selected.

So i am adding to my form builder a marketing rule like this

```
  ->add('marketingRules', 'entity', array(
                'required' =>'true',
                'class' => 'RecomendationsBundle:MarketingRule',
                'choices' => $builder->getData()->getProject()->getPlan()->getMarketingRules(),
                'property' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
```

This works as expected. But I would like to add an input field when one of the Marketing rules have been selected to be able to add parameters to the chosen Marketing rule.

I can do this manually by checking the form with JavaScript and adding the necessary inputs, but I am sure there must be a much better option.

Please let me know if I can make my case clearer. In my head sounds ok :(

Using: 
Symfony 2.5 (Is an old project)

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Does your entity have a particular field for such parameters? e.g. ruleParameters?

Comment: The requirement to which u r needed can be best achieved by EAV Model .  You can  look the link https://github.com/Padam87/AttributeBundle which is easy to implement .

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your comment. Yes, I do have a ruleParameters field which I want to be display if any of the check boxes of an specific marketing rule is selected. So for example, if you select season products is the marketing rule, you can pass as a parameter the kind of product like sport for sport related products of the season.

Comment: Ajeet Varma, Thanks for your comment, I will check your link and get back to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

FOr make the basic checkbox in a form you can use the current method :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
// ...

$builder->add('public', CheckboxType::class, array(
    'label'    => 'Show this entry publicly?',
    'required' => false,
));
```

After this you can add ""paramaters option" -> like an other add if checked".
The checkbox use like value true and false. But i haven't use these one.

The better solutions stay Jquery or also you can do this with css too. i explain :

**For CSS using** : 
add to your view a input like this :

```
<input class="reveal-if-active" name="TheNameYouWant" type="TheTypeYouNeed"/>
```

and css :

```
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px; /* little bit of a magic number :( */
  overflow: visible;
}
```

For your controller you can handle by hand the request :

```
$myvar = $request->request->get('TheNameYouWant');
```

And in the if($form is valid) you add this, before to persist :

```
$myObject->setValueNeeded($myvar);
```

It's a good way to use checkbox, if you're optionnal field is not required.

The best Way stay to use Jquery, for this one i have see that you already use it so don't necessary to said you how do that.

I'm not sure that you have solutions with Symfony except one that you can use with css method i have give you (for the controller and css keep the same method, just use this special parameter for the extra field :

```
->add('extra', null, array('mapped' => false)),
```

This gonna make your field optionnal and invisible on your view if you don't call it.
(for this one i refer to this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12766325/6795425)